# How to share the url of popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I found a code to load xml data to popup box. I tried to share the URL of the popup boxes. But the code is not support to share the URL. When try to open the URL of the popup in new tab, need to direct show the popup. How can I implement the code?

Here is the code I found.

```js
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"data.xml",
        dataType:"xml",
        success:xmlParser
    });
});

function xmlParser(xml){
    xml = $(xml).children();
    let total = $(xml).children().length;
    $(xml).children().each(function (idx) {     
        
        let tag = $(this).prop("tagName");
        let nextIdx = idx + 1;
        let prevIdx = idx - 1;
        //to make cyclic
        nextIdx = nextIdx == total ? 0 : nextIdx;
        prevIdx = prevIdx == -1 ? (total -1) : prevIdx;

        let image = '<img style="background-image:url(' + $(this).find("image").text() + ')"' + '" />';
        let image2 = '<div><img src="' + $(this).find("image").text() + '" width="100%" alt="' + '" />' + '</div>';
        let head = '<div>' + $(this).find("head").text() + '</div>';
        
        
        let html = `<div class="col-sm-4 random" id="random">
                    <div class="thumbnail randomdiv3" id="border" >
                    <a href="#${tag + idx}" id="openModalBtn">
                            <div>${image}</div>
                            <h5>${head}</h5>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                 </div>`;
        let popup = `<div id="${tag + idx}" class="overlay">
                <div class="popup">
                
                <a href="#${tag + prevIdx}" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
                <a href="#${tag + nextIdx}" class="next round">&#8250;</a>
                    <h6>${head}</h6>
                    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                    <div>${image2}</div>
                </div>
            </div>`;


        $("#xmldata").append(html);
        $("#popup").append(popup);
    });
}
```

```css
.overlay {
              position: fixed;
              top: 0;
              bottom: 0;
              left: 0;
              right: 0;
              background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
              transition: opacity 500ms;
              visibility: hidden;
              opacity: 0;
            }
            .overlay:target {
              visibility: visible;
              opacity: 1;
            }
            .popup {
              margin: 70px auto;
              padding: 20px;
              background: #fff;
              border-radius: 5px;
              width: 30%;
              position: relative;
              transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
            }
            .popup .close {
              position: absolute;
              top: 20px;
              right: 30px;
              transition: all 200ms;
              font-size: 30px;
              font-weight: bold;
              text-decoration: none;
              color: #333;
            }
            .popup .content {
              max-height: 30%;
              overflow: auto;
            }
            .thumbnail img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 272px;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 50% 20%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            position: inherit;
            }

            .previous {
            background-color: #000;
            color: white;
            padding: 8px 16px;
            }

            .next {
                background-color: #000;
                color: white;
                padding: 8px 16px;
            }

            .round {
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
```

```html
<div class="row" id="xmldata"></div>

<div id="popup"></div>
```

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/70HUWx64QlKhfMIh?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use url hash to share popup url

I have updated your [code](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/tynJehyJ3iZrMlfl?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview) little bit please check and let me know, every time you click on link to open the popup it will update your window hash and you can share that url to anyone which will open directly image popup

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Thanks a lot..!

Comment: Can I automatically disable the dialog box of hash enable?

Comment: i don't get it, can you please explain

Comment: ,When I try to open a popup, The browser always display a dialog box. How can I automatically disable that dialog box?

Comment: oh, actually i have put alert to show you the window url(just for example how your share url gonna look) you can remove it, find alert(window.location.href); in that plunker and remove it.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much..!